# Como establecer conexión con la api de wit.ai

Tags: ruby

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un chatbot utilizando wit.ai para montarlo en mi sito web, pero desde mi localhost claramente no tengo acceso a la API online...como puedo hacer para poder probarlo en mi local>>???

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Echa un vistazo al repositorio de [wit](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-ruby)

- Instala la gema wit con `gem install wit` desde la consola
- Descarga el [repositorio](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-ruby) para correr los ejemplos.
- Desde tu consola para correr los [ejemplos](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-ruby/tree/master/examples) que vienen en ese repositorio desde tu consola realiza el comando `ruby examples/basic.rb <your_token>`.

Necesitas tener tu token ese lo debes de poder conseguir en https://wit.ai/

Te aconsejo que veas el repositorio y corras los ejemplos para que te des una idea de cómo funciona.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder...esos pasos ya los había hecho, para descartar que fuese un problema de mi conectividad probé con la gema 'savon' y me funciona bién, pero al probar el ejemplo básico que está en Git el resultado es 'SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to api.wit.ai:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution)'(el acces_token también es el correcto lo verifiqué copia y pega desde la aplicación en wit), no sé si facebook tendrá alguna restricción de la API para mi país (Cuba) o si me falta alguna configuración..si tienes alguna respuesta lo agradecería mucho..Sldos

Comment: estas corriendo en vagrant, docker o local?

Comment: podrias intentar abrir un issue con tu error en https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-ruby/issues

Comment: Local, con el proxy del sistema configurado!!

Comment: sera porque tu aplicación esta corriendo en el puerto 3000,  al correr tu app intenta correr en el puerto 443 con rails s -p 443